# Filled square next to some Text

Tags: tikz-pgf, formatting, environments, text

Is there any way to produce a filled square next to some text? (with centered horizontal alignment)

[image]

I am quite new to LaTex and this is what I have tried so far:

```
\newenvironment{prioritized}[1]
    {
    \tikz \fill [orange] (0,0) rectangle (0.5,0.5);
    #1\\
    }
    { 
    }
```

Basically, it should be the design of the title text, and below it is a paragraph.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: [This recent answer of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/617741/204164) should be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: custom title]

Here you can add an argument for a different colour (with a default colour into the `newcommand`, which is olive here).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\newcommand{\prioritized}[2][olive]%
    {%
    \stepcounter{examp}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
        \node[fill=#1,minimum size=4mm,rounded corners] (rect) at (0,0) {};
        \node[right= 2mm of rect] {\bfseries #2};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }

\begin{document}
    \prioritized{First title}
    
    \lipsum[1][1-5]
    \medskip
    
    \prioritized[purple]{Second title}
    
    \lipsum[2][3-6]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow!! No way thank you so much :)